# Is it good to use one settings repository for multiple JetBrains products

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to use one settings repository for multiple JetBrains products without the setting and plugins from each IDE overriding each other?

For example:

- `Setting1` is the name of the setting repo
- I've connected `Setting1` to PhpStorm and WebStorm

**Can plugins of PhpStorm affect WebStorm?**

I have tried it and the settings seems to be clashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no; if you use one repository for all IDEs, settings would be synchronized cross-IDE, it can provoke conflicts and settings overwriting.

Similar functionality should be implemented in the [Settings Sync plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync) in the near future, but this feature doesn't use the configurable repository; all settings are stored on JetBrains cloud servers.